# Pause a thread to give user option to continue

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a thread that copies a file and give the progress bar the progress, I have a method the stops the filestream copy and kills the thread, I am trying to implement a jOptionPanel yes_no to ask the user if they are sure they want to delete. But i need to be able to pause the fileInputStream copy until the thread either stops or is continued. The thread waits but the file copy keeps going. how can i fix this? Any help would be great

First is the thread I want to pause

```
thr = new Thread("cool") {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                while (running == true) {
                    try {
                        newWorkFileName();
                        long length = fileIn.length();
                        long counter = 1;
                        int r;
                        byte[] b = new byte[1024];
                        fin = new FileInputStream(fileIn);
                        fout = new FileOutputStream(fileOut);
                        tvConvertInterface.updateJLabel2("Creating File");
                        while ((r = fin.read(b)) != -1) {
                            counter += r;
                            fout.write(b, 0, r);
                            prog = (int) Math.round(100 * counter / length);
                            tvConvertInterface.updateJProgressbar1(prog);

                        }
                        fin.close();
                        fout.close();
                        tvConvertInterface.disableStopBtn();
                        tvConvertInterface.updateJLabel2("Work File Created");
                        running = false;
                    } catch (NullPointerException | IOException ex) {
                        tvConvertInterface.disableStopBtn();
                        tvConvertInterface.updateJLabel2("File is not valid");
                        Logger.getLogger(TvConvertGutts.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                        tvConvertInterface.updateJProgressbar1(0);
                        running = false;
                    }
                }
            }
        };
```

Next is the Method that i want to implement the jOptionPanel

```
public boolean terminate() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        synchronized (thr) {
            thr.wait();//MAKES THREAD WAIT

            //I NEED TO PAUSE THE FILESTREAM AND BE ABLE TO RESUME
        }
        int n = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(
                null, "SURE YOU WANT TO DELETE?",
                "Kill It Dude",
                JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
        if (n == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
            fin.close(); //CLOSE INPUT STREAM
            fout.flush();//FLUSH OUTPUT STREAM
            fout.close(); //CLOSE OUTPUT STREAM
            thr.interrupt();//KIILL THE THREAD
            System.out.println(thr.getState());//PRINT STATE OF THREAD
            TvConvertInterface bst = new TvConvertInterface(null, true);
            bst.disableStopBtn();//SET PROGRESSBAR TO 0
        } else if (n == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION) {
            synchronized (thr) {
                thr.notify();//DONT DELETE AND CONTINUE
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("spewin");
        }

        return false;
    }
```

This terminate method is called by a button click. From a class called TvConvertInterface

```
private void jButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        try {

            check.terminate();
        } catch (IOException ex) {

            Logger.getLogger(TvConvertInterface.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
```

Comment: how would we know what its doing and how its implemented?

Comment: the thr Thread is about. I will edit my question to show the Button event

Comment: Wait does not what you think it does. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/guardmeth.html

Comment: What would be a good way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

**You are using the JAVA concurrency API incorrectly**.

The `object.wait()` will pause the current thread and the `object` in this case would serve as a monitor object.

What you need to do is the following:

1. define a `boolean shouldPauseThread` variable
2. the while loop should check for the value in this variable; if it is true you should wait on a monitor object
3. if the user approves the cancelling, then the thread should end its execution, so there needs to be a check for another variable `boolean stopThread`
4. if the user wants to continue with processing, you will just reset the `shouldPauseThread` variable and notify on the previously used monitor object
5. you need to handle all the transitions from the mentioned states

Comment: Okay i will try it keeps tell me non-static method wait() cannot be referenced from a static context
---- how do i solve this

Comment: According to the java memory model this is not guaranteed to work. The second thread may never see the change of the boolean variable's value unless it is declared volatile. Also this is a hack. Use a real lock instead e.g. ReentrantLock if you use Java SE7 or higher.

Comment: @Crazyjavahacking sorry im really struggling with this could you explain more

Comment: Im still totally lost on this.